# Terraria error: No suitable graphics card found

Tags: 14.04, wine, chromebook

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and Terraria on my Chromebook, but when I try to open Terraria I get this error message:

```
No suitable graphics card found.
```

Comment: What's your graphics hardware and driver (see the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'`)? How *exactly* did you install Terraria? How does [tag:wine] come into play here and in which version and which configuration?

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in [this post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/105600/discussions/0/43099721695343811/?l=spanish), you can get `terraria` working in Ubuntu with `wine` by following these quoted steps:

All you need is:

- Wine 1.7.X
- Microsoft .Net package 3.5 and 4
- The Microsoft XNA package.

Make sure you have downloaded the complete `wine` from either Ubuntu Software Center or another source.

1. Download and install `wine`. Then download the `WINDOWS` version of Steam (Has a extension `.exe` or `.msi`), install it, run it and log in, verify all the things you need to and start downloading `terraria`.
2. While waiting for the download, go to your `Configure Wine` menu and a XP looking window should come up.

   Click on graphics. Then check the first box (Automatically capture the mouse in full-screen windows.
3. Once Terraria has finished, Install .NET and XNA setups you have just downloaded. Terraria relies on these!

Run Terraria and everything should work!

Enjoy!

This also works with games like CS:GO except they don't need XNA or .NET!

Comment: I reverted your edit, since 14.04 is supported until April 2019 (according to https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life)